# Find the value used for XOR

Tags: encryption, xor

I have the initial address and the output .. I need to find out what was used for XOR

```
129.94.5.93:46 XOR ????? == 10.165.7.201:14512
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XOR has an interesting property that if you apply it to one of its operands and the result, you get the other operand back. In other words, if

```
r = a ^ b
```

then

```
b = r ^ a
```

where `a` and `b` are operands, and `r` is the result.

Hence, the data with which the original has been XOR-ed is

```
139.251.2.148:14494
```

Here is a short program in C# to produce this result from your data:

```
var a = new[] {129,94,5,93,46};
var b = new[] {10,165,7,201,14512};
var c = new int[a.Length];
for (int i = 0 ; i != a.Length ; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
    Console.WriteLine("a={0} b={1} c={2} back={3}", a[i], b[i], c[i], c[i] ^ a[i]);
}
```

[Here is a link to ideone showing this program in action.](http://ideone.com/YS92HU)

Answer (score 1):

XOR is a "reversible" function of sorts so:

A XOR B = C
A XOR C = B

therefore if you just XOR the 2 values that you do have you will be able to get the missing number

so

129.94.5.93:46 XOR X == 10.165.7.201:14512

x == 129.94.5.93:46 OXR 10.165.7.201:14512

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to figure this out is to look at the binary representation of each number (let's take the first number on each side):

```
     129 = 10000001
XOR  139 = 10001011
======================
     010 = 00001010
```

From this we can see that `129 XOR 139 == 10` is equivalent to `129 XOR 10 == 139`.